# Data in Snowflake table is AUTOMATICALLY encrypted using AES 256 bit or 128 bit?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Data in Snowflake table is **AUTOMATICALLY** encrypted using AES 256 bit or 128 bit?

According to documentation, these are two conflicting statements that I found. Which is correct

[image]

[image]

Comment: AES 256-bit encryption

Comment: How did you come to that conclusion. In the pictures above, there are two conflicting statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Data in Snowflake table is AUTOMATICALLY encrypted using AES 256 bit
> or 128 bit?

If you are asking the data in a Snowflake **Table**, it's encrypted using AES 256 bit:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-encryption.html#encryption-key-management

All Snowflake customer data is encrypted by default using the latest security standards and best practices. Snowflake uses strong AES 256-bit encryption with a hierarchical key model rooted in a hardware security module.

For internal **stages**, the encryption can be configured to use 256-bit encryption:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters.html#label-client-encryption-key-size